# Why was MS-Sql Server uninstalled from my ubuntu 20.04 desktop?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall, mssql

I just went out to use ms-sql server and I discovered that it was completely uninstalled from my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop.

Why would the software be uninstalled without my knowledge?

It also uninstalled the command-line tools (sqlcmd etc.) and I had to reinstall those as well.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve actually got the same issue twice now, new Ubuntu 20.04 server and found that it’s been uninstalled.. I’ve used a tool called appitude and it shows any package conflicts which could be causing it to autoremove if you tried to update anything..
If you try running that and go to the Database tag you should be able to see any issues there, really is a great tool.

Install the package:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Open the Term GUI:

```
sudo aptitude
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check out aptitude.

Comment: No worries, if there is any other issues post them here 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it was uninstalled, but I went back out to:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15 and followed the steps and successfully installed the latest version.
I'm assuming the problem occurred due to some update removing it and failing to add the latest version, but I'm not sure.

Oddly enough, it had not removed everything -- my sa user still had the original password I had set.  It does indeed look as if an update removed but didn't re-install sql server.

I also had a struggle getting the sql command line tools installed.
The following command failed because I had a missing dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

I ran the following in an attempt to uninstall old version:

```
sudo apt-get remove mssql-tools
```

After that when attempting to install the mssql-tools it stated that I was missing dependencies.
I installed each one of those dependencies and was finally able to run the original installation of mssql-tools unixodbc-dev and it worked.

There is additional info about installing mssql-tools at : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15